# How to use gomega's ContainElements matcher with a custom equality matcher

Tags: go, testing, gomega

In a test I have a list `actual` of elements with a struct similar to this:

```
type MyStruct struct {
     Field1 string
     Field2 int32
     .
     .       // a long list of other fields
     .

}
```

I want to assert that `actual` contains the elements of a list of expected elements, but only considering `Field1` and `Field2`, the other fields are not relevant for the test. I would like to use the `ContainElements` matcher with some "magic" custom matcher like in this pseudo code:

```
expected := []MyStruct{{Field1: "value1", Field2: 1} ...{Field1: "value2", Field2: 2}}
Expect(actual).To(ContainElements(expected), <custom matcher>)
```

I have been looking at the `WithTransform` matcher as in [1] but I have been unable to figure out how to use it in this context.

[1] http://eng.rightscale.com/2015/11/30/composing-gomega-matchers.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use MatchFields(IgnoreExtras, Fields{}) to compare only given fields so in your case it should look something like:

```
ContainElement(MatchFields(IgnoreExtras,Fields{
                    "Field1": Equal("Value1"),
                    "Field2": Equal(int32(42)),
                }))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the customized gomega matcher [respect](https://github.com/JiaYongfei/respect) directly. It looks like

```
expected := []MyStruct{{Field1: "value1", Field2: 1} ...{Field1: "value2", Field2: 2}}
Expect(actual).To(Respcet(expected))
```